# Paypal: Sorry, we couldn't set up your subscription using the payment method you selected. Please try another payment method

Tags: paypal

**Sorry, we couldn't set up your subscription using the payment method you selected. Please try another payment method.**

Dears i have this issue with all customers no paypal customers service available to answer me i am losing money and customers due this issue. PLEASE ANY ONE HELP.

**Sorry, we couldn't set up your subscription using the payment method you selected. Please try another payment method.**

i am sure no issue with banks accounts only from paypal side.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because whatever it’s about, programming doesn’t seem to be involved.

Comment: Did you figure it out? I'm in the same trouble.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a decline message. If *all* payments are being declined, it may have something to do with your business type or other account settings, but only someone on PayPal's end would be able to look at your account and research these declines.

It is not an integration nor a programming problem for Stackoverflow.